# Chromium fresh build displays "Pardon the Interruption" page on some of websites

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium

I successfully installed Chromium on window according to the instructions in  official documentation, but when I run chrome.exe after installing it, I encounter a problem on some of websites. Instead of loading the page, I am redirected to a page that says:

"Pardon the Interruption
As you were browsing something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:

You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.
You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser
A third-party browser plugin, such as No Script is preventing JavaScript from running."

I did not modify anything after the fresh installation, and also these websites work properly on other browsers like Chrome and Mozilla. How can I resolve this issue and make those websites work correctly on my Chromium build?